# Problem with WHERE Clause in SOSL to search KnowledgeArticles

Tags: sosl

I am trying to search case,solution and KnowledgeArticles with following SOSL

```
FIND 'lithium' RETURNING Dissusion__kav (Title, Summary, LastPublishedDate, KnowledgeArticleId, UrlName WHERE PublishStatus = 'Online'), questionAndAnswer__kav (Title, Summary, LastPublishedDate, KnowledgeArticleId, UrlName WHERE PublishStatus = 'Online'), Case__kav (Title, Summary, LastPublishedDate, KnowledgeArticleId, UrlName WHERE PublishStatus = 'Online')
```

but on executing I am getting this Exception

`You must specify a language WHERE clause for knowledge articles in this API version`

But WHERE clause is already included .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [Question related to SOSL and Knowledge Articles](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F000000090iLIAQ), you need to append `WHERE Language = 'en_US'` at the outermost level:

```
... UrlName WHERE PublishStatus = 'Online') WHERE Language = 'en_US'
```